# Merging n CSV strings ignoring headers from every string except the first one

Tags: scala

```
val csvDataWithHeader1 = 

s"""SubId,RouteId
    |332214238915,423432344323
    |332214238915,423432344323""".stripMargin

val csvDataWithHeader2 = 

s"""SubId,RouteId
    |332214238915,423432344323
    |332214238915,423432344323""".stripMargin

val csvHeaders = List(csvDataWithHeader1, csvDataWithHeader2)
```

Reading 'n' CSV files of same type as strings. Trying to get rid of additional headers when merging them.

Wondering if I should eliminate the headers before merging the strings or after merging (by splitting and eliminating duplicates). Is there a significant performance benefit for one approach over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO from a performance standpoint, it is highly beneficial to eliminate the headers of each individual csv file and then merging them together. To eliminate the header you can delete the first element of the list which happens in O(1) time.

Whereas, to remove duplicates from the list, if you use the `list.distinct`, then it has an additional overhead of creating a Hashset internally to remove duplicates.

```
 /** Builds a new $coll from this $coll without any duplicate elements.
   *  $willNotTerminateInf
   *
   *  @return  A new $coll which contains the first occurrence of every element of this $coll.
   */
  def distinct: Repr = {
    val b = newBuilder
    val seen = mutable.HashSet[A]()
    for (x <- this) {
      if (!seen(x)) {
        b += x
        seen += x
      }
    }
    b.result()
  }
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation.  I can take headers from first file and pass it around for other files. Wondering if there's a better way to do this. As of now, I parse individual files and use mkString("\n) which is why there's header duplication.

Comment: For each csv file parsing, you can convert its contents to List[String] and perform the operation of removing the first line which is the header of the file instead of reading the whole csv file as a single string. In that way, you can eliminate the header and have a final list of multiple csv file contents.

Comment: If this answers your question, you may please accept it or if you need any further clarifications please let me know. Thanks !!!

Comment: won’t that result in lot of list objects? @ChaitanyaWaikar